# Voltage source in series with dependent curent source. How to solve for voltage source?

Tags: dc, circuit-analysis, bjt, current-source, thevenin

I am trying to calculate the high frequency cut off of a common collector BJT circuit.  I replaced Cu with a test voltage and open circuited the other capacitors.  The circuit I came up with has the test voltage in series with a current source.  I am just unsure how to find the test voltage.  Here is the work I have done so far.  I just can't figure out what an expression for Vt would be or how to relate it to the other variables.  I needto find Vt/it

[image]

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how to include Vt in my algebraic expressions.

Comment: Never mind my earlier comment. It is a trick question. Vt will not affect the answer because the dependent current source will just generate an opposing voltage if needed to obtain the current it wants to output.

Comment: Ok then.  In the original problem I have Vt replaced with a capacitor and I am trying to solve for the open circuit time constant.  How would I solve for that if I can't know Vt?

Comment: @chasep255 - Does dv/dt = i/C ring any bells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your small-signal diagram is wrong. If this is a CC amp then collector should also be at AC ground. And this means that Cu capacitor is connected between the base and the ground. And the resistance seen by this capacitor is simply equal to: 
$$R_u=R_a||(r_{\pi}+(\beta+1)R_E)$$